# How to leave empty the search pattern in Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: c#

`Directory.Getfiles(@"path","searchpattern",SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

How can I leave the pattern empty?

I want to get all files of a directory and its subdirectories. But I don't want a search pattern.

`""` Doesn't work when I do it no results is shown.

I tried writing `null` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Wildcard symbols. 
`Directory.Getfiles(@"path","*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)` should be what you're looking for.

You can check the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

Comment: it worked thank you. i actually checked the document 2 times but idk why i didn't try that sorry.

Comment: @ZekiKral it's crucial to understand the documentation. Always check the `Overloads` section to see what options you have and select the one that fit's your situation.